# How to control SSL in Wordpress for automatically changing http to https?

Tags: ssl, domain, https

I have a domain and one subdomain. The domain has a installed SSL with valid certificate but the subdoamin doesn't have it. I have a link from domain's wordpress header.php file that pointing main page in subdomain. The link supposed to be as HTTP but it was changed to HTTPS. I edit header.php file but after update the file it changed to HTTPS again. 
I installed Wordpress HTTPS plugin in domain wordpress. 
What I have done:
The domain wordpress is located in Domain/app which I copy the files and folders to root directory (Public_Html) a by Godaddy technician's suggestion (my domain is from Godaddy). 
The subdomain wordpress is a clone from the main wordpress.

Please let me know how to change this link to HTTP. I appreciate it in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable SSL on the WordPress side and let the web server handle it by configuring a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS on the web server side, only if the user calls the main domain.

You may also want to read WordPress's official documentation about SSL from these two pages:

- [Administration Over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)
- [HTTPS for WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/)

Note that it is considered bad practice to serve your WordPress from both HTTP and HTTPS URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The title and last line of your question conflict, in the title you want HTTPS as the end result, in the final line your asking for HTTP. I assume the title is correct.

Don't use a WP plugin for this.  I don't have a godaddy account, but most commonly you would want an .htaccess file in the domains root that redirects traffic not on port 443 to HTTPS.

See here: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8828/automatically-redirecting-visitors-to-https

Comment: GoDaddy offers pretty good support options as well for WordPress & SSL : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-secure-a-wordpress-website-with-ssl-certificate?replies=7